Inputting missing data
I have the below data, with items randomly missing that can be calculated based on other columns:



CAD-JPY
CAD-USD
USD-JPY
...




109.050
0.741
Null
...


Null
0.742
147.765
...



For example, in the first row, USD-JPY = CAD-USD \* CAD-JPY for the missing USD-JPY pair. In the second row, CAD-JPY = CAD-USD \* USD-JPY for the missing CAD-JPY pair.
Expected output:



CAD-JPY
CAD-USD
USD-JPY
...




109.050
0.741
147.165
...


109.040
0.742
147.765
...



There are 10 pairs, so finding cross pairs to calculate from is difficult.
I tried to load into python to calculate all the missing rates, but I wonder if it could be done entirely within SQL.

And did you try anything?

That's not how currency conversion works. You can transfer from currency A to currency B to currency C and back to currency A and make a profit.  Secondly, you should use a normalised structure, where you have three columns; currency_from, currency_to, exchange_rate.

What criteria are you using to determine values for null fields. for example where did you get 109.040 under CAD-JPY if it (rate) is coming table I think yes it would be possible to use SQL alone using loops and where conditions

@Gnyasha I would hardly recommend loops.
